Better proof that homology groups $H_{m-1}(M; \mathbb{Z})$ and $H_{m-2}(M; \mathbb{Z})$ are torsion-free (Lefschetz Duality)?
I attempted to prove this problem yesterday using Alexander Duality. There was a critical issue of trying to prove a stronger case of the Whitney embedding theorem, (that I think is false or can't easily be found online). While falling asleep I think that I came up with a shorter, stronger proof using Lefschetz duality. There is no similar example or proof that I saw in Hatcher's book; the proof is my own.

Question: Let $M$ be an $m$-dimensional manifold $(m \geq 3)$, compact, simply connected, and with non-empty boundary. Show that the homology groups $H_{m-1}(M; \mathbb{Z})$ and $H_{m-2}(M; \mathbb{Z})$ are torsion-free.

Proof: In our diagrams and expressions, infix $\leftrightarrow$ represents an isomorphism. We only have one function for each domain/range pair, so we'll suppress notation and simply draw our arrows. We're always working over $\mathbb Z$, and we'll suppress that part of the notation also. Hatcher's definition of the $\text{Ext}$ functor corresponds to $\text{Ext}_R^1$ seen in other sources. For the sake of this problem, we only care that $\text{Ext}$ returns the torsion subgroups of any finitely generated group.
The diagram below gives an overview on how to write the proof:

The top isomorphism is given by Lefschetz duality, and the horizontal rows are exact sequences.
Setting $k = 1$, Lefschetz duality tells us that $H_{m-1} \leftrightarrow H^1\left({M, \partial M}\right)$.
From the split exact sequence, we see that any torsion contribution must come from $\text{Ext}\left(H_{0}(M, \partial M) \right)$. But the zeroth homology groups are always torsion free. As a consequence, $H_{m-1}(M)$ is torsion free.
Setting $k =2$, it follows that $H_{m-2} \leftrightarrow H^2 (M, \partial M)$. From the split exact sequence, any torsion coefficient must come from $\text{Ext}\left(H_1(M, \partial M) \right)$. The underlying relative homology group is derived by a section of the long exact sequence  of reduced homology groups
$$ \tilde H_1(M) \rightarrow \tilde H_{1}(M, \partial M) \rightarrow \tilde H_0 (\partial M) \rightarrow \tilde H_0(M)$$
Now, $M$ is simply connected, so $\tilde H_1 (M) \leftrightarrow 0$. Similarly, $M$ is a single connected component, so the reduced homology group $\tilde H_0(M) =0$. This gives us a short exact, sequence, and we are able to discover that our arrow in the middle is an isomorphism:
$$ 0 \rightarrow \tilde H_{1}(M, \partial M) \leftrightarrow \tilde H_0 (\partial M) \rightarrow 0$$
Since $\tilde H_1 (M) = H_1 (M)$, we can see that $H_1(M, \partial M)$ must be isomorphic to a zeroth homology group, which has to be torsion free. Then there is no torsion contribution to $H^2(M, \partial M)$. Thus $H_{m-2}(M)$ must be torsion free.

Is this the correct usage of Lefschetz duality and the universal coefficient theorem? That is, does it work as I described and correctly prove the theorem?
